# Concatenate Lines in Bash

Tags: sed, awk

Most command-line programs just operate on one line at a time.

Can I use a common command-line utility (echo, sed, awk, etc) to concatenate every set of two lines, or would I need to write a script/program from scratch to do this?

```
$ cat myFile
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4

$ cat myFile | __somecommand__
line 1line 2
line 3line 4
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /;'
```

Grab next line, and substitute newline character with space.

```
seq 1 6 | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;'
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Comment: `printf "%s\n" {1..6} |  sed 'N;s/\n/ /;'`.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ awk 'ORS=(NR%2)?" ":"\n"' file
line 1 line 2
line 3 line 4

$ paste - -  < file
line 1  line 2
line 3  line 4
```

Comment: +1 for paste.  Note, the default delimiter is tab, use `-d""` if you truly want your lines smashed together.

Answer (score 1):

Not a particular command, but this snippet of shell should do the trick:

```
cat myFile | while read line; do echo -n $line; [ "${i}" ] && echo && i= || i=1 ; done
```

Comment: UUOC. `while read line; do echo -n $line; [ "${i}" ] && echo && i= || i=1 ; done < File`

Comment: Heh, I wasn't familiar with UUOC until you posted that. For simple cases, I still think cat is clearer even if it's slightly slower and wastes a process. :-)

Comment: Like to have the subject (input) first English speakers do.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Perl as:

```
$ perl -pe 'chomp;$i++;unless($i%2){$_.="\n"};' < file
line 1line 2
line 3line 4
```

Comment: `perl -ne 'chomp($p=$_); $q=<>; print $p,$q' file`

Comment: @glenn: That is neat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shell script version that doesn't need to toggle a flag:

```
while read line1; do read line2; echo $line1$line2; done < inputfile
```